# Dirichlet function on [a,b]

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let the Dirichlet function be given by

$$f(x):=\begin{cases} 1 &\text{if } x\in \mathbb{Q},  \\{}\\ 0 &\text{if } x\in  \mathbb{R} \setminus  \mathbb{Q},.\end{cases}$$

Then $f$ is measurable on  [a,b].

My professor said me to try this: $f$ is measurable since 
$$ \{ x \in \mathbb{R}| \ \ f(x)>\alpha \} = \begin{cases} \emptyset &\text{if } \alpha \geq 1,  \\{}\\ \mathbb{Q} &\text{if } 0\leq \alpha <  1 \\{}\\ \mathbb{R} &\text{if }  \alpha <  0\end{cases}$$

And then since $\emptyset$, $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are measurable sets, we have that $f$ is measurable.

But I don't understand why if $\alpha \geq1$, $0\leq \alpha <  1$ and $\alpha <  0$ we have the last sets, and why this implies the measurability on all [a,b]? Could someone can explain me, please?...

Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: Note for others: $\Bbb{II} = \Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q$ here.

Comment: Yea are the irrationals.

Comment: Knight: [nobody uses double i here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/450524/328173).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First case

To find $\{ x \in \mathbb{R} \ | \ f(x)>\alpha \}$, where $\alpha \ge 1$:

$$\begin{array}{cl}
&\{ x \in \mathbb{R} \ | \ f(x)>\alpha \} \\
\subseteq& \{ x \in \mathbb{R} \ | \ f(x)>1 \} \\
=& \varnothing
\end{array}$$

This is because the range of $f$ is $\{0,1\}$, so $f(x)$ can never be greater than $1$.

### Second case

To find $\{ x \in \mathbb{R} \ | \ f(x)>\alpha \}$, where $0 \le \alpha < 1$:

$$\begin{array}{cl}
&\{ x \in \mathbb{R} \ | \ f(x) > \alpha \} \\
=& \{ x \in \mathbb{R} \ | \ f(x)=1 \} \\
=& \Bbb Q
\end{array}$$

### Third case

To find $\{ x \in \mathbb{R} \ | \ f(x)>\alpha \}$, where $\alpha < 0$:

$$\begin{array}{cl}
&\{ x \in \mathbb{R} \ | \ f(x) > \alpha \} \\
=& \{ x \in \mathbb{R} \ | \ f(x)=0 \lor f(x) = 1 \} \\
=& \{ x \in \mathbb{R} \ | \ f(x)=0 \} \cup \{ x \in \mathbb{R} \ | \ f(x)=1 \} \\
=& (\Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q) \cup (\Bbb Q) \\
=& \Bbb R
\end{array}$$

### Conclusion

The main thing to notice here is that the range of $f$ is $\{0,1\}$, i.e. $f(x)$ can either be $0$ or $1$.

Comment: So the measurability of $f$ on [0,1] not in [a,b]?

Comment: The **range** of $f$ (which by the way is $\{0,1\}$ not $[0,1]$) has nothing to do with the **domain** wherein it is measurable.