# What's a good source on how to construct all sets of numbers?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation, peano-axioms

Lately I've been interested in building, formally, all sets of numbers, starting from ℕ, then ℤ, then ℚ, then ℙ, then ℝ, then iℝ, then ℂ.

The only book I have come up, so far, is "Foundations of analysis" by Edmund Landau, which seems to build them like this : ℕ, ℤ and ℚ, ℝ, ℂ. Is that one a good book? which other source would you recommend?

This would also include the mathematical operations each set has.

Also, I'm corious about why ℕ⊂ℤ⊂ℚ, (ℚ∪ℙ)⊂ℝ, ..., and so on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could also have a look at John Conway's On Numbers And Games.

Comment: What's $\Bbb P$?

Comment: You acn see Jürg Kramer & Anna-Maria von Pippich, [From Natural Numbers to Quaternions](http://www.springer.com/la/book/9783319694276), Springer (2018).

Comment: @G.S, from context, I'd say the real algebraics.

Comment: In my answer to [Is the real number structure unique?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2246085/is-the-real-number-structure-unique/2249868#2249868), I posted a list of 9 textbooks each of whose primary purpose is the construction of various number systems.

Comment: ℙ = {x|x is an irrational number}

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450524/is-there-an-accepted-symbol-for-irrational-numbers

Comment: The accepted answer to that question, Daniel, says "But if and when an alternative letter like ℙ or  is used, it should be preceded by a clear statement as to the fact that it is being used to denote the set of irrational numbers." Moreover, you are not using it to represent the irrational numbers, but the *real* irrational numbers. E.g., $\sqrt{-1}$ is irrational.

Comment: True that, thanks for the correction.